# Why if i have continues plot mark the label is only at the first mark

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

If have continuous plot marks, the label is only displayed on the first mark. Is there anyway to change this behavior? I want each candlesticks to have 2% display.

```
plot(stopLossPrice, color=color.rgb(255, 153, 0), title="Stop Loss Mark", linewidth=2, style=plot.style_steplinebr, offset=offset)
if (na(stopLossPrice[1]) and not na(stopLossPrice))
    label.new(bar_index, stopLossPrice, text=StopLoseText, style=label.style_label_up, color=color.new(#00f708, 100), textcolor=color.rgb(255, 153, 0), size=size.small)
```

[image]

The label is only displayed at the first mark if its a continuous plot marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a condition (`(na(stopLossPrice[1]) and not na(stopLossPrice))`) to create the labels.

`stopLossPrice` the price you are plotting. By looking at the image, once you start ploting this, `na(stopLossPrice[1]` will no longer be `true`. Therefore, you will not get new labels for the next candles.

If you want to create the labels for each candle, just remove that condition.

```
if (not na(stopLossPrice))
    label.new(bar_index, stopLossPrice, text=StopLoseText, style=label.style_label_up, color=color.new(#00f708, 100), textcolor=color.rgb(255, 153, 0), size=size.small)
```

**Note:** You should ensure that `stopLossPrice` will be set to `na` when not used. Otherwise, it will keep creating labels.